# Passing string to python from time

Tags: python, bash, time, parameter-passing

I have a bash script called foo.sh that in this minimal example looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
time $@
```

and a python script bar.py:

```
#!/bin/env python
print sys.argv
```

I want to do something like

```
bash foo.sh python bar.py "foo bar"
```

and want "foo bar" to be apssed as a string to the python skript. However I get either

```
['bar.py', 'foo', 'bar']
```

or when I do:

```
bash foo.sh python bar.py \"foo bar\"
```

I get:

```
['bar.py', '"foo', 'bar"']
```

as output. How do I get "foo bar" to be passed and interpreted as a single string to the python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variable in the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
time "$@"
```